# What does the following sentence ‘including but that’ mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

What does the following sentence including 'but that’ mean?
Which is closest in meaning to the following sentence?
Or can you explain what it means more specifically if possible?

Who knows but that he may be right?

> (a) Possibly he is right.
> (b) Possibly he is not right.

Answer (score 0):

Meaning (a). Who knows that there is not some chance that he may be right? Maybe he is right?

> but that in American English
>
> 2. that there is not some chance that
>    *we can't be sure but that he's right*

[But that (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/but-that)